# Catch the URL and redirect somewhere else

Tags: php, redirect

i ve done this below menu in php which is autogenerated with a function :

As you know, if i click on "Red Chicken", it will try to open a ../Red%20Chicken URL, which doesnt exist till it comes from a big table which change everytime.

What i want to do is : to know where we clicked (example : by generating the url and cut it ) and then redirect to a page like result.php (+ get something like the variable to know where do we come from). And of course, i don't want to create a .php page for each element of my table.

Is this thing possible ?

EDIT : i found a way, it's to change my function and how it generates the menu.

Not really what i wanted but it's okay.

---

```
<ul class=\"niveau1\">

        <li class=\"sousmenu\"><a href=\"Food\">Food</li>
        <ul class=\"niveau2\">
                <li class=\"sousmenu\"><a href=\"Meat\">Meat</a></li>
                <ul class=\"niveau3\">
                        <li class=\"sousmenu\"><a href=\"Poultry\">Poultry</a></li>
                        <ul class=\"niveau4\">
                                <li class=\"sousmenu\"><a href=\"Red Chicken\">Red Chicken</a></li>
                        </ul>
                </ul>
                <ul class=\"niveau3\">
                        <li class=\"sousmenu\"><a href=\"Beef\">Beef</a></li>
                        <ul class=\"niveau4\">
                                <li class=\"sousmenu\"><a href=\"Hamburgers\">Hamburgers</a></li>
                        </ul>
                        <ul class=\"niveau4\">
                                <li class=\"sousmenu\"><a href=\"Steak\">Steak</a></li>
                        </ul>
                </ul>
        </ul>
        <ul class=\"niveau2\">
                <li class=\"sousmenu\"><a href=\"Dairy\">Dairy</a></li>
                <ul class=\"niveau3\">
                        <li class=\"sousmenu\"><a href=\"Cow\">Cow</a></li>
                </ul>
                <ul class=\"niveau3\">
                        <li class=\"sousmenu\"><a href=\"Sheep\">Sheep</a></li>
                </ul>
        </ul>
    </ul>
    <ul class=\"niveau1\">
        <li class=\"sousmenu\"><a href=\"url\">name</a></li>
    </ul>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/w10j0a38/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The PHP-Way would probably be to use URLs like `<a href='menuhandler.php?sel=cow'>Cow</a>`, and if you want to be lazy, you could also JS/jquery to manupulate the URLs and replace `<a href="something">`with a call in the style shown before - but then this would not work w/o JS, so it is not a real option IMHO.

Comment: Sorry, hadn't clicked on "Submit Answer" yesterday evening ;-)
Basically you're using a similar approach, generally I prefer querystrings like "var=val", because you can then easily check $_GET["var"] in your code and also pass multiple values/flags that way.

Comment: yea, this is what i have done, missed my own answer. giving you thumb up anyways for the further infos.

Answer (score 0):

changed my function to generate it in another way

```
<a href=\"Recette.php?var=food\">
```

Not really what i wanted but it's okay.